# Renderless Vue Component in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, renderless-component

I have a renderless component in JavaScript that I am trying to convert to TypeScript. I'm running into errors declaring the `render` function in a `Vue.extend`-ed component:

```
(method) ComponentOptions<Vue, unknown, unknown, unknown, never[], Record<never, any>>.render?(createElement: CreateElement, hack: RenderContext<Record<never, any>>): VNode
  No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
  Argument of type '{ render(): void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentOptions<Vue, DefaultData<Vue>, DefaultMethods<Vue>, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition<Record<string, any>>, Record<string, any>>'.
    Types of property 'render' are incompatible.
      Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '(createElement: CreateElement, hack: RenderContext<Record<string, any>>) => VNode'.
        Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'VNode'.ts(2769)
        vue.d.ts(90, 3): The last overload is declared here.
```

This is an example of what I am trying to do in TypeScript:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  render() { // error happens when I add this. I tried typing the render with :VNode
             // and returning this.$scopedSlots.default({}), but error still occurs
  }
})
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by - send props back to a parent component? Can you share original code snippet?

Comment: https://learn-vuejs.github.io/vue-patterns/patterns/#renderless-component this is what a renderless component is and this is what I want to achieve only with typescript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`render()` has this signature:

```js
render?(createElement: CreateElement, hack: RenderContext<Props>): VNode;
```

*Notes for `render()` declaration:*

- `hack` does not need to be declared in your code
- argument declarations are unnecessary in a renderless function
- return type is `VNode` (i.e., a single root node), but Vue actually accepts `VNode[]` as a return (which is what `this.$scopedSlots.default()` returns)

**Solution 1:** Specify the return type as `VNode`, and return a single node that wraps `this.$scopedSlots.default()`:

```js
import Vue, { VNode, CreateElement } from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  render(h: CreateElement): VNode {
    return h('div', this.$scopedSlots.default!({}))
  }
})
```

**Solution 2:** Use `any` type assertion on `this.$scopedSlots.default()` to workaround the type error:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  render() {
    // The container node is expected to provide a single root,
    // so it's okay to return `VNode[]` as any.
    return this.$scopedSlots.default!({}) as any
  }
})
```

Comment: solution 2 worked for me because the component is renderless. Thank you @tony19. This isn't available to know in the docs so thank you for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: I've got error using second solution, but using normal slot works fine: 
`render() { return this.$slots.default! as any }`

Comment: Yeah, above solution worked as long as I did not use mixin (defined unfortunetly as `any`). Adding mixin resulted in ts errors on every component property. Now I'm using `render(h) { return h('template') } and seems to work perfectly fine.