# Vue.js type of createElement in render functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I am using a vue-select plugin and render function is used to create custom buttons for it. Documentation: https://vue-select.org/guide/components.html#deselect

I am using class based components with TypeScript enabled and I want to render those two elements.

Currently I use them like this:

```
Deselect: object = {
    render: (createElement: any) => createElement('i', { attrs: { class: 'ri-close-line' } }),
}

OpenIndicator: object = {
    render: (createElement: any) => createElement('i', { class: { 'ri-arrow-down-s-line': true } })
}
```

It is working fine but I don't want to use "any" types. What type is createElement?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58002254/2170192

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right type is `CreateElement` imported from vue :

```
import  { CreateElement } from 'vue'


Deselect: object = {
    render: (createElement: CreateElement ) => createElement('i', { attrs: { class: 'ri-close-line' } }),
}

OpenIndicator: object = {
    render: (createElement: CreateElement ) => createElement('i', { class: { 'ri-arrow-down-s-line': true } })
}
```